# Video thumbnail not appearing in wordpress homepage

Tags: php, youtube, wordpress, youtube-api

[Here](http://vijaykumar.host22.com/) is my blog i added youtube video to my blog.[This](http://vijaykumar.host22.com/?p=8) is the post but my problem is iam not able to view the video thumbnail in my homepage. I the thumbnail or image of the video is not appearing in homepage.Can we fix by adding any plugin or we should code to do it?

Comment: Thumbnail is there, I can view it

Comment: yeah but i added the image it is not thumbnail of video it is just image i added to test watch it again sir.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your theme uses "the_excerpt" on the homepage, which is a stripped-down text-only version of your post. Some themes have the option to show the full post instead (look onder settings -> reading or under settings page of your theme).

If it is a Child Theme, you can manually alter the code to use "the_content" instead.